# Wanted: good definition of the term "lowering" in the context of compilers

Tags: compiler-construction, terminology

Can anyone point me to a good definition of the term "lowering" in the context of compilers?

From what I can tell, it is the translation of a higher-level operation into an equivalent combination of lower-level operations, but I'm not really sure, and I can't find one after a few minutes of searching on Google. (There are a few usages of "lowering" e.g. in [GCC](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/GNU_C_Compiler_Internals/GNU_C_Compiler_Architecture_4_1#Lowering_Passes) or [LLVM](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMBackend.html) but no references to a definition.)

Comment: Isn't this called `reducing`? Or maybe that's what it's called in grammar definitions, I can't remember.

Comment: Pretty vague. That's what the entire compiler does. I would call specific examples 'strength reduction', e.g. `*2` => `<< 1`.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Dr. Dobbs just published [an article by Walter Bright](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/so-you-want-to-write-your-own-language/240165488) (of dlang fame), where he mentions the term:

> ## Lowering
>
> One semantic technique that is obvious in hindsight (but took Andrei Alexandrescu to point out to me) is called "lowering." It consists of, internally, rewriting more complex semantic constructs in terms of simpler ones. For example, `while` loops and `foreach` loops can be rewritten in terms of `for` loops. Then, the rest of the code only has to deal with `for` loops. This turned out to uncover a couple of latent bugs in how while loops were implemented in D, and so was a nice win. It's also used to rewrite `scope guard` statements in terms of `try-finally` statements, etc. Every case where this can be found in the semantic processing will be win for the implementation.
>
> If it turns out that there are some special-case rules in the language that prevent this "lowering" rewriting, it might be a good idea to go back and revisit the language design.
>
> Any time you can find commonality in the handling of semantic constructs, it's an opportunity to reduce implementation effort and bugs.

Answer (score 11):

*The Dragon Book* doesn't use the term. Kennedy+Allen's *Optimizing Compilers for Modern Architectures A Dependence-based Approach* doesn't use the term. Steve Muchnick's *Advanced Compiler Design and Implementation* doesn't use the term.

*Engineering A Compiler* uses the term but doesn't define it. Bob Morgan's *Building an Optimizing Compiler* (1998) uses the term a lot and defines it.

> Lowering : The instructions are lowered so that each operation in the
> flow graph represents a single instruction in the target machine.

It is a more general term and there is no single definition. My own understand is that a compiler *lowers* an operation from a higher abstraction layer to a lower, for example, in LLVM lowering from MachineInstr to MCInst.

Answer (score 10):

I can't find a good link with a definition, but I think I can give a good example. In LLVM, the LLVM IR supports several sizes of integers. Most C/C++ compilers, including clang, support long long and a 64 bit data type. Many 32 bit processors, like the mips (32 bit), don't have instructions that can do, for example, a 64 bit add or compare. LLVM will "lower" these 64 bit operations to operations, usually 32 bit, that the processor can do.

In the case of a int64_t compare for example, LLVM will lower it to

```
compare the upper 32 bits with a signed comparison
if they are equal, compare the lower 32 bits with an unsigned comparison
```

Some lowering can get pretty fancy. For example on a processor that does not support a multiply instruction, simple multiplies might turn into shifts and adds while more complicated ones might turn into a call to a run-time supprt library.