# What does a LoweringError mean?

Tags: python, cuda, jit, numba

I am attempting to execute the following kernel

```
from numba import cuda
import numpy as np

@cuda.jit
def Dark_Pix_Search_Kernel(all_bands,window_size,output_array):
    row_size = all_bands.shape[0]
    col_size = all_bands.shape[1]
    end_r = row_size - (row_size -row_size*int(row_size/window_size[0])) - window_size[0] + 1
    end_c = col_size - (row_size -row_size*int(row_size/window_size[0])) - window_size[0] + 1
    row,col,band_n = cuda.grid(3)

    if (row in range(0,end_r,window_size[0])) and (col in range(0,end_c,window_size[0])):
        row_e = row+window_size[0]
        col_e = col+window_size[0]
        output_array [row][col][band_n] = np.median(all_bands[row:row_e, col:col_e,band_n])
```

but I am getting the following error

```
LoweringError: No definition for lowering <built-in method impl_contains_helper of _dynfunc._Closure object at 0x000002851EB23F98>(range_state_int64, int32) -> bool
```

Comment: The if condition is blowing up the compiler.  Don't use in range, write the blinds explicit

Comment: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252876/wanted-good-definition-of-the-term-lowering-in-the-context-of-compilers) may be of interest.  The [numba jit compiler flow](https://archive.fosdem.org/2019/schedule/event/python_extending_numba/attachments/slides/3098/export/events/attachments/python_extending_numba/slides/3098/extending_numba.pdf) involves several conversions from one form of representation of your code to another (e.g. numba CUDA  to llvm IR, as one example).  Lowering may occur as the compiler seeks to "rewrite" or recast your code in the confines of the new representation

Comment: @talonmies thanks for the insight! I've tried changing the if condition but it would seem that the np.median() is actually the culprit. As far as I know, np.median is supported by cuda. Any other insights?

Comment: @RobertCrovella this is actually quite insightful. Thanks!

Comment: No Numpy functions are supported  in numba kernel code

Comment: @DavidRaphael: I have provided a short answer community wiki answer to get this question off the unanswered queue , if you care to either upvote it or accept it

Answer (score 1):

Lowering errors occur when the Numba compiler can't emit simplified boilerplate ("lowering") for built-in operators and functions in Python code.

There are actually two errors here.

1. The lowering error comes from the use of `range`, which is unsupported in Numba CUDA kernels
2. Once that error is fixed, you will get an error from  `np.median`. No numpy functions are supported in Numba CUDA kernels

So in effect, there is no real fix for the error. You will have to reconsider the design of your code.