# Private field of class instance mysteriously resets to default when it shouldn't

Tags: c#

I'm using C#10 and .NET6. Two days I'm struggling with understanding why private field `counter` of class instance `Internet` resets to 0. Here is my oversimplified code. Notice the comment where I expect returned value to be 1 but it is 0. Why it happens and how to fix it? I need to save the structure of class hierarchy.

```
internal class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        GoogleModule g = new();
        foreach (var i in g.Parser.Parse())
        {
            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Press enter to exit.");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
}

public class GoogleModule : AbstractModule
{
    public override AbstractParser Parser => new GoogleParser();
}

public abstract class AbstractModule
{
    public abstract AbstractParser Parser { get; }
}

public class GoogleParser : AbstractParser
{
    protected override Internet www => new();
    public override IEnumerable<string> Parse()
    {
        yield return www.Get(); //expected 0 and it is
        yield return www.Get(); //expected 1 but it is 0!!!
    }
}

public abstract class AbstractParser
{
    protected abstract Internet www { get; }
    public abstract IEnumerable<string> Parse();
}

public class Internet
{
    int counter;
    public string Get() => counter++.ToString();
}
```

Comment: You're using lambdas to define your properties - which means *each* time the property is accessed, those `new()`s run again.

Comment: Every time you access `GoogleModule.Parser`, it creates a **new** `GoogleParser` instance. That's probably not what you want: I suspect you want to have a single `GoogleParser` instance, and every access to the `Parser` property returns that same instance. Use `public override AbstractParser Parser { get; } = new GoogleParser()`

Comment: Wow! I didn't know those are lambdas. I thought it is just syntactic sugar. Thanks guys, now it works as I expect!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is this:

```
protected override Internet www => new();
```

This is an [expression-bodied member](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/statements-expressions-operators/expression-bodied-members). It [lowers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20252876/wanted-good-definition-of-the-term-lowering-in-the-context-of-compilers) into a getter with a single return statement that returns the expression after the `=>`:

```
protected override Internet www {
    get { return new Internet(); }
}
```

Therefore, the getter is called *two* times when `Parse` is called:

```
public override IEnumerable<string> Parse()
{
    yield return www.Get();
    yield return www.Get();
}
```

*Each time*, a new instance of `Internet` is created. Since it is a new instance, `counter` is of course the default value 0.

You probably meant to say this instead:

```
protected override Internet www { get; } = new();
```

This declares a property with a backing field, that has an initial value of `new()`. i.e. this lowers into something like this:

```
private readonly Internet www__BackingField = new Internet();

protected override Internet www {
    get { return www__BackingField; }
}
```

[See the lowering happen on sharplab.io!](https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgZgpghgLgrgJwgZwLQGMD2A3KCCWUAdjKkvAkcgDQAmIA1AD4ACATAIwCwAUCwMwACdoICSJCJQgxeAb16DFg/CUFY4EhAG4FSgcI4AGQQHFpACgCUggLwA+NZg0xJDBgDoAKpgDKMAkQA5lY6PAC+vLz6IgDCgvI8SoIADgiYLugutGKaRNKCAO5FHPGCgdJagmG2gnkFIbqKqekQmRDZ4i5SMIVFbLYOdQ3hQA=)

The same applies for

```
public override AbstractParser Parser => new GoogleParser();
```

I think it would make sense for this to have a backing field too, but either way this doesn't really affect the output of the program in this particular program, since you are only accessing `Parser` once.